# Evaluate the line integral shown below

Tags: calculus

Could someone tell me if my solution to the below problem is correct?

$\int_C 3xy\mathrm{d}y$ where $C$ is the quarter-circle $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ from $(0,2)$ to $(-2,0)$.

my solution is:

$$x = 2\cos t$$
$$y = 2\sin t$$
$$\mathrm{d}y = -2\sin t$$

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} 3(2\sin t)(2\cos t)(-2\sin t)\mathrm{d}t = 8$$

Comment: Looks right to me

Comment: For some reason it is not letting me edit but the bounds should be from pi/2 to pi not the other way around.

Comment: @TehRod edited. i think it is correct now, do you agree?...thanks for the help

Comment: Your parametrization is incorrect...yet the final result is right. It should be $\;x=2\cos t\;,\;\;y=2\sin t\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio actually it doesn't matter because x^2+y^2=4 regardless of which one comes first

Comment: As it stands, you are integrating from $(2,0)$ to $(0,-2)$. It would have been more "natural" to let $x=2\cos t,\,y=2\sin t$.

Comment: Now that you have "corrected" the parameterization, the bounds on the integral should go from $\frac{\pi}{2}$ tp $\pi$.

Comment: @TehRod It matters a whole lot... **but in this case**, by sheer coincidence, it doesn't as the vector field is symmetric. Using the limits the OP chose, he actually integrate over the arc of circle from $\;(2,0)\;$ to $\;(0,-2)\;$, i.e.: on the fourth quadrant instead of on the second one, as intended...

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales how about now?

Comment: Well, as it currently stands (since it keeps changing) he is integrating "backwards" fro  $(-2,0)$ to $(0,2)$.

Comment: Looks correct now.

Comment: If $y=2\sin(t)$, then it would seem that $\mathrm{d}y=2\cos(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there seems to be a comment war we can settle this with an answer... with the parameterizations given we get $\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} 3(2\cos t)(2\sin t)(2\cos t)\text{d}t$ which evaluates to 8 so you were correct haha

Comment: Actually the original "setup" was incorrect, thus the "comment war" although the numerical result was correct.